# What types of variables to various machine learning techniques support

Tags: machine-learning, variable-types

Is anyone aware whether someone has produced a cheatsheet--preferably like a summary table--of various machine learning techniques (e.g. kNN, regression tree, Naive Bayes, linear regression, neural nets, etc.) along with the type of dependent and independent variables they accept (continuous, categorical, binary, etc.)?

I realize there can be a lot of shifty grey area here, but a general guide of some sort could be helpful for becoming familiar with these tools. I've done a lot googling not turned up anything like this yet.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://ml-cheatsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

It covers basic regression as well as popular neural net architectures.

Also check out this compact infographic: https://blogs.sas.com/content/subconsciousmusings/2017/04/12/machine-learning-algorithm-use/

A nice one as well: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio/algorithm-cheat-sheet

Comment: The cheat-sheet you shared is good. But, the OP is really interested in variable types as to which techniques accept what kind of variables. For example, what if all the variables are categorical, the OP needs to have a look in cheat sheet which techniques accept dependent as well as independent variables as categorical.